# How to do stateful aggregation using flatMapGroupsWithState?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I am getting following error message while applying `flatMapGroupsWithState`.

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: flatMapGroupsWithState in update mode is not supported with aggregation on a streaming DataFrame/Dataset;

Following is what I am trying to do.

- Read messages from Kafka & Parse It
- Group based on certain dimensions
- Ran UDAF for every group and calculate an aggregation per group. `agg` doesn't return `KeyValueGroupDataSet`, so applying `groupByKey` on previous step output to group based on `aggFunction` column
- Merge this aggregates to previous state of stream using `flatMapGroupsWithState`.

Getting error message for the last step.

Does this error means I cannot apply `flatMapGroupsWithState` after applying `agg(....)` on dataset?

Answer (score 3):

> Does this error means I cannot apply `flatMapGroupsWithState` after applying `agg(....)` on dataset?

Not really. It says that (highlighting mine)...

> **flatMapGroupsWithState in update mode** is not supported with aggregation on a streaming DataFrame/Dataset

That means that you use the default **output mode** which is `update`, but should rather be `complete` or `append` as described in the Spark official documentation [Output Modes](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#output-modes) (see "Queries with flatMapGroupsWithState" query type).

[image]

---

From the comment:

> Also `flatMapGroupWithState` does support update operation. From `KeyValueGroupedDataset`, `if (outputMode != OutputMode.Append && outputMode != OutputMode.Update) { throw new IllegalArgumentException("The output mode of function should be append or update") }`

You're right that `flatMapGroupWithState` supports append and update output mode, but only when given as part of the input parameters. See the signature of `KeyValueGroupedDataset.flatMapGroupWithState`:

```
flatMapGroupsWithState[S, U](
  outputMode: OutputMode, // <-- HERE
  timeoutConf: GroupStateTimeout)(
  func: (K, Iterator[V], GroupState[S]) ⇒ Iterator[U]): Dataset[U]
```

In other words, `OutputMode` appears twice in a streaming query:

1. For the streaming query itself (in `DataStreamWriter.outputMode` with `append` output mode as the default)
2. In `KeyValueGroupedDataset.flatMapGroupWithState`

The exception refers to *"flatMapGroupsWithState in update mode"* (i.e. `flatMapGroupsWithState` with the update output mode as an input argument) which is OK.

It is not OK *"with aggregation"* (i.e. in a streaming query with a streaming aggregation of any kind `groupBy`, `groupByKey`, `cube`, `rollup`, etc.)